# How to solve Error: Invalid JSON RPC response on DigitalOcean

Tags: contract-deployment, dapp-development

I have deployed my dapp front end and backend on Digital Ocean.
On running the server.js I am getting below error

```
(node:30490) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

Below settings in my server.js code use to work fine on my local Ganache,

```
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");
```

I suspect I need to make changes in web3 provider to make it compatible to run on DigitalOcean but cannot figure out them, please help...

Comment: Since you are not planning to install a geth node in your server I'd recommend to register with Infura.io and obtain a url to connect.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to access the dapp from your local environment, change the `localhost` to your rpc provider node ip address.

```
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://node_ip_address:8545");
```

Comment: I want to run my dapp (front end and server) on Rinkeby Network. In the server.js file I have created event listeners for solidity events. Please suggest how can I implement that.